# keeping a: active until another link is clicked

Tags: css, hyperlink

I have a list of links - not a menu bar - as in

```
<div align="right"><a href="me1.cfm?pic_ws=80&typ=1" target="mnfrm3">ME1</A></div><br>
<div align="right"><a href="me2.cfm?pic_ws=80&typ=1" target="mnfrm3">ME2</A></div><br>
<div align="right"><a href="me3.cfm?pic_ws=80&typ=1" target="mnfrm3">ME3</A></div><br>
```

and use the standard css

```
a {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #C65B05;
}

a:hover   {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #03B003;
}
```

what I would like to do is have the link selected to stay the hover color until a different link is clicked on in the same window. (page contains iframes but this is top page so i don't want the state to change if a link is clicked on in iframe)

Comment: are you allowed/familiar to JQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HTML: (*Added `onclick="clickSingleA(this)"` and `class="single"` attributes.*)**

To have one of the links activated by default, just add `active` class

```
<div align="right"><a onclick="clickSingleA(this)" class="single active" href="me1.cfm?pic_ws=80&typ=1" target="mnfrm3">ME1</A></div><br>
<div align="right"><a onclick="clickSingleA(this)" class="single" href="me2.cfm?pic_ws=80&typ=1" target="mnfrm3">ME2</A></div><br>
<div align="right"><a onclick="clickSingleA(this)" class="single" href="me3.cfm?pic_ws=80&typ=1" target="mnfrm3">ME3</A></div><br>
```

**CSS: (*added a.active*)**

```
a {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #C65B05;
}

a:hover, a.active   
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #03B003;
}
```

**JavaScript: (*function to activate links, and remove old active*)**

```
function clickSingleA(a)
{
    items = document.querySelectorAll('.single.active');

    if(items.length) 
    {
        items[0].className = 'single';
    }

    a.className = 'single active';
}
```

Comment: this works great on all browsers. decided to split hover and active with different colors and that works too....

since when landing on the page the first link's action is the default display in iframe is there a way of having that link being active by default?

tnx

Comment: @Andy I've updated answer, I've also commented here but as I see now that was not posted.