# How can I make an effect last on an element in a nav menu (CSS)

Tags: javascript, html, css, nav

How can I effect a pressed on element until I press on another element ?

exmple:

HTML:

```
 <nav>
  <a href="#"> ex1 </a>
  <a href="#"> ex2 </a>  
  <a href="#"> ex3 </a>
 </nav>
```

CSS:

```
 a:active {
 background-color: darkblue;
 }
```

I once did before but now I forgot how..
Is it by the pseudo class :active or is this pseudo class effect ends when releasing the mouse click?

How can I make it last until I click on another element in the nav menu ?

Thank You...

Comment: You will have to use a bit of JavaScript. Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25579888/keeping-a-active-until-another-link-is-clicked

Comment: The link above is probably the correct solution. But the CSS selector `a:focus` (rather than `a:active`) could also be what you want, depending on what you're looking for.

Comment: maybe `a:focus {...`  ?